# Open an image saved in SD card with option to crop it as in Gallery to apply as wallpaper

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I have a application where I have some downloaded images in a folder in **SD Card**. I want to save it as a wallpaper.

using the below code user can set it as wallpaper.

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(loadedImage);
```

However this does not bring up any UI for user to select a part of the image like crop operation when selecting a image from Gallery app to set wallpaper. I would like my code to trigger such a operation. When users click a button in my app I want to take them to gallery app with crop option to set the wallpaper.

Please let me know how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: which Android version do you target?

Comment: Hi @Shinigamae: I want to support from 2.1. But if it is only possible from a particular version, I am okay with it.

Comment: I did have a simple project, on 2.3. I allow user to choose an image from his library (saved from a website before) then allow him to crop that image. But I found out it didn't work well on Android 3.0 and 4.0. Need some work-around then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this:

1. To select from your library (SD Card included) - **void selectPhoto()**:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setType("image/*");
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose photo to upload"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
   ```
2. To start the crop action - **void doCrop()**:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
   intent.setType("image/*");

   // Check if there is image cropper application installed.
   List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );

   int size = list.size();

   // If no cropper application is found, throw a message.
   if (size == 0) {            
       Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       return;

   // If there're cropper applications found, use the first
   } else {

       // Specify image path and cropping parameters
       intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
       intent.putExtra("outputX", 0);
       intent.putExtra("outputY", 0);
       intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

       Intent i = new Intent(intent);
       ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
       i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
       startActivityForResult(i, CROPPED_IMAGE);
   ```
3. Handle Activity results - **void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)**

   ```
   if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

   switch (requestCode) {
       case PICK_FROM_FILE: 
           mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
           doCrop();
           break;          
       case CROPPED_IMAGE:         
           Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
           try{
               if (extras != null) {
                    Bitmap myImage = extras.getParcelable("data");
               }
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           break;
   ```

This code will activate crop action right after you selected the image.

Note that *mImageCaptureUri* is the selected image URI, it would be pass to intent of cropping action.

Comment: Thank you for the code. A little bit of adjustments and it works perfectly.